# I have using fpdf and fpdi but error through in class file blow the code

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php
use vendor\setasign\fpdi\src\Fpdi;
use vendor\setasign\fpdi\PdfReader;

require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/Fpdi.php');

require_once('vendor/setasign/fpdi/src/FpdiTrait.php');
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

//Through the error in fpdi class
$pdf = new Fpdi();
```

**Fatal error:** Class 'vendor\setasign\fpdi\src\Fpdi' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Mari\pdf\file_pdf.php on line 35

```
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('benchbook.pdf');
$pageId = $pdf->importPage(1, PdfReader\PageBoundaries::MEDIA_BOX);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useImportedPage($pageId, 10, 10, 90);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: it looks like you're using composer, you should instead just `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';` at the top and remove the other `require_once` statements. If you still have issues use the command `php composer.phar install -o` [[sic](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install)]. Aside from that if the `vendor` is in `../` then any other `require_once` statements to it need to updated as well.

Comment: https://github.com/codedge/laravel-fpdf check this

Comment: Class 'FPDF' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\Mari\FPDI-master\src\FpdfTpl.php on line 21 This error through